# Autohotkey map middle mouse button to CTRL+S

Tags: keyboard, autohotkey, remap

I am trying to use autohotkey to remap the middle mouse button to the combination CTRL+S (makes for easier saving when I am writing). Right now my code looks like: `MButton::Send {^s} Send {up} return`. While this does save, at the same time it also enters the words "return" and "send" on whatever page I am saving. I have also tried `MButton:LCtrl+^s` but that does not work either. Can anyone help with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you managed to write this code without (at least seemingly) having opened the documentation.

But well, anyway, you're going to want to use the [remapping syntax](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm#Remap), and then you'll end up with this:
`MButton::^s`
And that's all.